# How to check whether a Throwable is a result of an invalid e-mail address

Tags: java, exception, jakarta-mail

Note: My current solution is working (I think). I just want to make sure I'm not missing anything.

**My question:** I'm wondering how to check whether an exception was caused because an invalid e-mail address. Using Java Mail.

Currently I'm checking [SMTPAddressFailedException](http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/com/sun/mail/smtp/SMTPAddressFailedException.html)s with [getAddress()](http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/com/sun/mail/smtp/SMTPAddressFailedException.html#getAddress%28%29) and [AddressException](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/mail/internet/AddressException.html)s with [getRef()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/mail/internet/AddressException.html#getRef%28%29).

Here's my current method for conducting the check. *Am I missing anything?*

```
/**
* Checks to find an invalid address error in the given exception. Any found will be added to the ErrorController's
* list of invalid addresses. If an exception is found which does not contain an invalid address, returns false.
*
* @param exception the MessagingException which could possibly hold the invalid address
* @return if the exception is not an invalid address exception.
*/
public boolean handleEmailException(Throwable exception) {
  String invalidAddress;
  do {
    if (exception instanceof SMTPAddressFailedException) {
      SMTPAddressFailedException smtpAddressFailedException = (SMTPAddressFailedException) exception;
      InternetAddress internetAddress = smtpAddressFailedException.getAddress();
      invalidAddress = internetAddress.getAddress();
    } else if (exception instanceof AddressException) {
      AddressException addressException = (AddressException) exception;
      invalidAddress = addressException.getRef();
    }
    //Here is where I might do a few more else ifs if there are any other applicable exceptions.
    else {
      return false;
    }
    if (invalidAddress != null) {
      //Here's where I do something with the invalid address.
    }
    exception = exception.getCause();
  } while (exception != null);
  return true;
}
```

---

Note: In case you're curious (or it's helpful), I use the [Java Helper Library](https://github.com/kentcdodds/Java-Helper) to send the e-mail (see this [line](https://github.com/kentcdodds/Java-Helper/blob/master/src/com/kentcdodds/javahelper/helpers/EmailHelper.java#L135)) so that's where the error is thrown initially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't usually need to cast exceptions; that's why you can have multiple catch blocks:

```
try {
    // code that might throw AddressException
} catch (SMTPAddressFailedException ex) {
    // Catch subclass of AddressException  first
    //  ...
} catch (AddressException ex) {
    // ...
}
```

If you are worried about nested exceptions, you can use Guava's `Throwables.getRootCause`.

Comment: That's a good point and in any other case this is what I would do. However, in my particular case I'd prefer to use a method to check. Anyway, you get the answer for the reference to Guava's `Throwable.getRootCause` :) Thanks!